# How to get the difference of two time stamps that are in two different rows?

Tags: php

Here's the data I have fetched from the data base.

```
| Starttime | Stoptime |
| 06:35:00  | 13:05:00 |
| 13:17:00  | 16:38:00 |
| 16:48:00  | 03:07:00 |
```

I have to get the difference of starttime of second row and Stoptime of first row

i.e. `13:17:00-13:05:00 + 16:48:00-16:38:00`

I have written the following code but I couldn't get the result

```
$sql->execute();
$row[]=$sql->fetch();
for($i=0,$j=1,$k=0;$i=count($row[0]);$i++,$j++,$k++){
    $sum += TIMESTAMPDIFF('MINUTE',$row[$j][$i-$k] , $row[$i][$j-$k]);
}
```

Comment: I think you have a typo. Did you mean to assign `$i=count($row[0])`, or was it supposed to be a comparison operator `==`?

Comment: Yea Thank you.I haven't noticed it

Comment: Well I am unable to format exactly the rows I have fetched.I couldn't add a break to each row.Imagine a break after every two words n please have a look at the query

Answer (score 1):

Before fetching data in mysql use the function "timediff" for starttime and endtime

```
select 
    *, timediff(stoptime, starttime) as time_diff 
from 
    table_name;
```

Note: datatype of two columns are set to be time for using this function. This is the most simplest way to get the solution

Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff

Answer (score 0):

You can use the php function [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to obtain a unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC). Since the timestamp is just an integer, then it is easy to just substract, add or do whatever you want with it.

```
$sum += strtotime($row[$i][$j-$k]) - strtotime($row[$j][$i-$k]);
```

Also, I suspect there's something wrong with your indexes and exit condition. If you want to compare the *first column* of row `$i+1` with the *second column* of row `$i` for all rows, you'd need to compare `$row[$i + 1][0]` and `$row[$i][1]`, taking care to exit the loop at length-1, so `$i+1` is never out of range.

Comment: I could hardly find no difference between your query and mine but what u said has worked fine.Thanks alot

Answer (score -3):

Get time-stamp in the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Now remove all the `'-',' ',':'` and you will get integer number.
Subtract this from the other time-stamp you are comparing with.

The answer you get, convert that into the format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

You will get the difference.

Comment: If I understand what you mean, the difference between '2017-12-02 09:53:30' and '2017-12-02 09:54:20' would give you '0000-00-00 00:00:90', which doesn't make much sense

Comment: Doesn't  '0000-00-00 00:00:90' tell you that the seconds difference in 90 secs, minutes difference is 00 mins, hours difference is 00 hours and so on?

Comment: Yes, that's technically true. But see the OP is adding the differences. Following your logic, two pair of dates that are 90 seconds apart would give you '0000-00-00 00:01:80', or 2 minutes, 20 seconds. When we know that 180 seconds are 3 minutes. This would get more complicated if there were differences in other fields.

Comment: Well I am unable to format exactly the rows I have fetched.I couldn't add a break to each row.Imagine a break after every two words n please have a look at the query

Comment: @Ángela the difference between times in the seconds column will never exceed 60 because its max value is 60 and min is 0, we just gotta do some math and we will get the difference easily